# Add new data row to XML with PHP with multiple attributes

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, simplexml

I am wanting to add a new row to an XML file with WordPress after my custom post type has been saved. I am rather confused about how to add a new row but with multiple attributes for each row. Each row of my XML file is as follows

```
<markers>
    <marker name="" lat="" lng="" type="" address="" phone="" hours1="" />
    <marker name="" lat="" lng="" type="" address="" phone="" hours1="" />
    <marker name="" lat="" lng="" type="" address="" phone="" hours1="" />
</markers>
```

For each new store that I save I want it to add all the data to one new row. I don't know if I need to create a new child then add that, as I've never really added data to an XML file before, surprsingly. My code for my current file is as follows

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
$stores = get_posts( array( 'post_type'=>'store', 'numberposts'=>-1 ) );
$xml->addChild('markers');

$name = $_POST['post_name'];
$lat = $_POST['wpcf']['latitude'];
$lng = $_POST['wpcf']['longitude'];
$type = $_POST['wpcf']['features'];
$address = $_POST['wpcf']['address'];
$phone = $_POST['wpcf']['telephone'];
$hours1 = $_POST['wpcf']['mon-fri'] . ", " . $_POST['wpcf']['saturday'] . ", " . $_POST['wpcf']['sunday'] ;

 $xml->stores->addChild('marker');
 $xml->stores->addChild('name', $name);
 $xml->stores->addChild('lat', $lat);
 $xml->stores->addChild('lng', $lng);
 $xml->stores->addChild('type', $type);
 $xml->stores->addChild('address', $address);
 $xml->stores->addChild('phone', $phone);
 $xml->stores->addChild('hours1', $hours1);

$file = SITE_URL() . '/testing.xml';
$open = fopen($file, 'w') or die ("File cannot be opened.");
fwrite($open, $xml->asXML());
fclose($open);
```

Comment: Have you tried [addAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php)?

Comment: Damn how didn't I realise that! I have been staring at this code way too long I am missing out the simplest things! Thank you :)

Comment: Happens to the best of us, brotato. Glad you've got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to achieve the XML output you are looking for is (some attributes omitted):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
$xml->addChild("markers");
$xml->markers->addChild("marker");
$xml->markers->marker->addAttribute('lat', 0);
print_r($xml->saveDoc());
```

Will output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml><markers><marker lat="0"/></markers></xml>
```